# How to use a proper type Function on a generic function?

Tags: typescript, type-safety

I'm trying to fix the [`@typescript-eslint/ban-types`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) lint errors:

> warning  Don't use `Function` as a type  @typescript-eslint/ban-types

I agree that `Function` is an unsafe type and should be replaced with a proper function type, such as `() => void`.

But my code is a little complex, and I have no idea how to avoid it here since I'm using `typeof` that returns a `Function`.

Here's a simplified version of my code. The full version is [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/blob/611a30f19145e7294efdc587efc863410c900604/packages/opentelemetry-context-async-hooks/src/AbstractAsyncHooksContextManager.ts#L60-L81).

```
function start<T>(args: unknown[], couldBeAFunction: T) {
  if (typeof couldBeAFunction === 'function') {
    runFunction(args, couldBeAFunction); // couldBeAFunction now is a Function
  }
}

function runFunction<T extends Function>(args: unknown[], target: T) {
  target.apply(args, args);
}
```

I can't replace `runFunction<T extends Function>` with `runFunction<T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>`, otherwise I'll receive the following error on the `runFunction` call:

> Argument of type 'T & Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: unknown[]) => unknown'.
> Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...args: unknown[]): unknown'.ts(2345)

How can I solve this lint error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use typeguard:

```js
type Fn = (...args: unknown[]) => unknown

const isFn = (fn: unknown): fn is Fn => typeof fn === 'function'

function start<T>(args: unknown[], couldBeAFunction: T) {
  if (isFn(couldBeAFunction)) {
    runFunction(args, couldBeAFunction); // couldBeAFunction now is a Function
  }
}

function runFunction<T extends Fn>(args: unknown[], target: T) {
  target.apply(args, args);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXFAK5wDWcA9gO5wDaAugJRIB8pF1dAsAFD8AxlTj5gUAJb54SVADM4xMpVpxmxBZPywEiDqEhU5UTYjNQA5HLKDgEkRf79rcW-YRicwADwAVNig4BEpcqkwANFDCJAA2ACYAQhAAgjA2diLEvqwA3vxQksYoUvAo0fFJqenuzLn5BVDYZGmuGXCBePiR5YkpLW4izADcUAD0o1FUsb1Vre5Q3FpQmLDVIvUAvvxbAnwuAwhNcP1tflAQAB7AEHBx2vABQUScKnQRUMBBEMBZdXwFnzw3zQmDAYBiIA6BEiT2G2yAA)

Comment: Thanks, but in my specific case, I can't change the generic constraints because `bind` is the implementation of an interface with the following type: `bind<T>(context: Context, target: T): T;`

Comment: please share your specific implementation

Comment: The functions that I'm working on: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/blob/611a30f19145e7294efdc587efc863410c900604/packages/opentelemetry-context-async-hooks/src/AbstractAsyncHooksContextManager.ts#L60-L81

Here's if the `bind` into the interface: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-api/blob/d28c68e67be364188ef53be7e880facbddd00b98/src/context/types.ts#L68